# making Jtable with add,delete,reset and sorting

Tags: java, swing, jtable, addition

Hey does anyone know how to make program using JTable with some function with the column that contain variable type: String, Double,Int so it will contain 3 column with different variable

- add Row in table (JButton)
- Delete Row in table (JButton)
- Reset the Table(JButton)
- Sorting function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object obj[][]=null;
Table.setModel(obj);
```

Add row but updating 'obj' and again call Table.setModel(obj);
Delete row same as above.

for reset table

```
 table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]
                {
                    {null, null},
                }
            ) {
                Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] {
                public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                boolean[] columnEditables = new boolean[] {
                public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
             });
```

Sorting :: 
I don't know what are you trying to sort but values can be extraxted via getModel()

```
TableModel Model= T.getModel();
```

After that you may sort the values and then reinsert into the table by

```
Model.setValueAt(value,int row,int column);
```

Comment: for adding row see [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

Comment: for deleting see [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsDeleted%28int,%20int%29)